# Issue regarding building an image Carousel with jQuery

Tags: jquery

i have developed a carousel with jquery where one images are showing one after one but i made some mistake in html for which something flashing when this line execute.

```
$('.headerCarouselwrapper :first-child').fadeOut().next('img').fadeIn()
```

here is my full jquery and html code. please see and guide me how make it smooth transition.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var bba = {
            init: function () {
                this.slideshow();
                return this;
            },
            slideshow: function () {
                $('.headerCarouselwrapper img:gt(0)').hide();
                setInterval(function () {
                    $('.headerCarouselwrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper');
                }, 5000);
                $('.partsbaseCarouselwrapper img:gt(0)').hide();
                setInterval(function () {
                    $('.partsbaseCarouselwrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.partsbaseCarouselwrapper');
                }, 5000);
                $('.careerbaseCarouselwrapper img:gt(0)').hide();
                setInterval(function () {
                    $('.careerbaseCarouselwrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.careerbaseCarouselwrapper');
                }, 5000);
                $('.knowledgebaseCarouselwrapper img:gt(0)').hide();
                setInterval(function () {
                    $('.knowledgebaseCarouselwrapper :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.knowledgebaseCarouselwrapper');
                }, 5000);
                return this;
            }
        };

        $(document).ready(function () { bba.init(); });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="headerCarouselwrapperOuter" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="headerCarouselwrapper">
            <img src="Images/new-bba-header-image1dyna.jpg" alt=""  style="width: 100%"/>
            <img src="images/new-bba-header-image2dyna.jpg"  alt=""  style="width: 100%"/>
            <img src="images/new-bba-header-image3dyna.jpg"  alt=""  style="width: 100%"/>
            <img src="images/new-bba-header-image4dyna.jpg"  alt=""  style="width: 100%"/>
        </div>
    </div> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. why build a carousel when there are sooooo many you could use, 2. if you insist, a jsFiddle would help a lot

Comment: here is js fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/hx9jy3ne/ but not sure why images is not showing when path is right.

Comment: is there any way to see who is giving me negative vote for my post from stackoverflow site ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use `css` `position` to make sure the images are atop one another, this will fix the jumping effect
2. break the animation into two function calls so the second starts before the first finishes
3. Pass a time interval to `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` and tweak them until the desired effect is achieved

It would also help if all the images were made to be the same height.

```js
     var bba = {
         init: function () {
             this.slideshow();
             return this;
         },
         slideshow: function () {
             $('.headerCarouselwrapper img:gt(0)').hide();
             setInterval(function () {
                 $('.headerCarouselwrapper :first-child').fadeOut(1000);
                 $('.headerCarouselwrapper :first-child').next('img').fadeIn(400).end().appendTo('.headerCarouselwrapper');
             }, 5000);
         }
     };
    
     $(document).ready(function () {
         bba.init();
     });
```

```css
.myImgs {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.headerCarouselwrapperOuter {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
  background-color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="headerCarouselwrapperOuter">
        <div class="headerCarouselwrapper">
            <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/images/new-bba-header-image1dyna.jpg" alt="" class="myImgs" />
            <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/images/new-bba-header-image2dyna.jpg" alt="" class="myImgs" />
            <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/images/new-bba-header-image3dyna.jpg" alt="" class="myImgs" />
            <img src="http://www.bba-reman.com/images/new-bba-header-image4dyna.jpg" alt="" class="myImgs" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: done already. did u understand my issue. see each image is flashing before fadeout.....effect is not smooth.

Comment: please check this jsfiddle url http://jsfiddle.net/tridip/hx9jy3ne/3/ and guide me how to make this carousel transition smooth ?

Comment: sorry, I was responding to "here is js fiddle link jsfiddle.net/tridip/hx9jy3ne but not sure why images is not showing when path is right."

Comment: check my last js fiddle link  jsfiddle.net/tridip/hx9jy3ne/3 and tell me how to fix it for smooth carousel transition.

Comment: can u please update code in your js fiddle because i paste your new code which is not working perfectly.

Comment: @Mou are you pasting the body tag into your page where you already have a body tag? http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/hx9jy3ne/5/

Comment: sorry it was my mistake to paste the code. now it is ok. thanks